# .net core does not publish all folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NetCore 2 application which works fine when launched from Visual Studio.

I've spent few days trying to publish it, I have already read all online documentation I have found with no luck.

When I access to localhost the screen appears on white, all images and styles disappear. HTML is there, instead, but some access to database does not work either.

I think there is a problem adding folders, because it is not exporting Views folder, or Moderls. Just the .Core usual dll files. it includes some dll and precompiledviews.dll with the name of the application.

[image]

Webconfig file is simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ApplicationName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It's true that Visual Studio is removing the views from .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\Clients\Create\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Clients\Edit\partials\PasswordForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Clients\Edit\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Devices\Edit\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Experts\Create\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Experts\Edit\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Experts\Edit\partials\PasswordForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Profile\Client\partials\ClientForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Profile\Client\partials\ClientPasswordForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Profile\User\partials\UserForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Profile\User\partials\UserPasswordForm.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Users\Create\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Users\Edit\partials\Form.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Users\Edit\partials\PasswordForm.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But if I change "None" with "Content" I can't compile because there is a error message saying that they are duplicated. I guess they are added into dll files.

Do you know what can I be missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How are you trying to publish the application? Are you using the built in publish tool? Or are you manually copying the files?

Comment: Copying the files, like I use to do on ASP.Net MVC. Is it wrong on .Core 2?

Comment: Well I wouldn’t recommend coping files, put it that way. I would suggest you look into how the publish tool works. Then I think your issues may disappear.